# Post with REST API on Wordpress.com [Error 401, not allowed]

Tags: wordpress, rest

I want to post articles with rest on one of my wordpress.com websites (wordpress website hosted on the free wordpress.com platform).

Endpoint, GET on: `https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/donnadulcinea.wordpress.com/posts`

With Basic-Auth header. Body of the request (for test),

```
{"title":"New Rest Post"}
```

Response:

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

What's wrong? Where may I found one final example for a really simple posting on a wordpress.com domain?

Comment: Try the Application passwords plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, are you using the basic auth plugin? [here](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth)

Second, I'm not sure if your endpoint is correct. This is how I use:

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

I tried in my website, with this json:

```
{
    "title":"title",
    "content":"content",
    "categories":"news",
    "status":"publish"
}
```

and it worked

Comment: i was fool trying so many plugins but "JSON Basic Authentication" was the plugin who did the job simple solution great answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue. Download the [miniOrange API Authentication plugin](https://plugins.miniorange.com/wordpress-rest-api-authentication).
Then, if running on an Apache server, add the below two lines to your `.htaccess` file after the `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Works like a charm.